# Openshift equivalent of Kubectl expose pod

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am fairly new to `openshift`.

Is there a `REST API` available to `expose` a pod ?
Basically I am looking to do something like:

```
kubectl expose pod pod-name
```

Comment: It's there, just use the same endpoint that you would use in Kubernetes

Answer (score 1):

### `oc expose`

Just like in `kubectl` - `expose`

As per [OpenShift CLI (oc) man](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/cli_reference/openshift_cli/developer-cli-commands.html#expose)

> #### expose
>
> Expose a Service externally as a Route.
>
> Example: Expose a Service
>
> $ oc expose service/parksmap-katacoda
>
> Example: Expose a Service and specify the host name
>
> $ oc expose service/parksmap-katacoda --hostname=www.my-host.com

### `virtctl expose`

Also, you can use [`virtctl expose`](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/cnv/cnv-using-the-cli-tools.html)

> The `virtctl` client is a command-line utility for managing container-native virtualization resources. The following table contains the `virtctl` commands used throughout the container-native virtualization documentation.
>
> `virtctl expose <vm>`
>
> Create a service that forwards a designated port of a virtual machine or virtual machine instance and expose the service on the specified port of the node.